# Compiling ffmpeg only for converting images to video(w/ sound)

Tags: android, build, ffmpeg

Ok, so I have successfully **compiled ffmpeg for android** using the **Guardian Project** source code. Now the binary comes out around 10 MB. But since it has to goto a phone, i just wanted it to be **as small as possible**.
Now The Guardian Project code has a file [configure_ffmpeg.sh](http://pastebin.com/5G0pvm0v)(goto link to see) which it says to change to add/remove functionality. But i have no clue what does what. So could some help me out sorting this. Ideally I would be able to disable a few things.

Thanks,
Digvijay

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the size of the project I don't know what you could do.

Regarding the conversion of images to a video, you could do something like:

public static String convert(File file) {

```
    FFmpegFrameGrabber frameGrabber =
            new FFmpegFrameGrabber(file.getAbsolutePath());

    String newName = file.getName();
    newName =
            newName.replace("." + FileManager.getExtension(file),
                    "_RECODED.mp4");
    String newFilePath = file.getParent() + "/" + newName;
    FFmpegFrameRecorder recorder;
    Frame frame = new Frame();
    recorder = new FFmpegFrameRecorder(newFilePath, 250, 250);
    recorder.setFrameRate(20);
    recorder.setFormat("mp4");
    recorder.setAudioChannels(2);
    recorder.setPreset("veryfast");
    try {
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("" + startTime);
        Log.d("Tempo", "" + startTime);
        frameGrabber.start();
        recorder.start();
        while (true) {
            try {
                frame = frameGrabber.grabFrame();
                if (frame == null) {
                    System.out.println("!!! Failed cvQueryFrame");
                    break;
                }
                recorder.record(frame);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("converter", e.getMessage());
            }
        }
        frameGrabber.stop();
        frameGrabber.release();
        recorder.stop();
        recorder.release();
        long stopTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println(""+stopTime);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return newFilePath;
}
```

This actually get every frame from an input video and creates another .mp4 video. You could just rewrite it to code from every frame in your folder (or anything like that).

Comment: hi wamasa,how to merge audio and video by using javacv? is it possible in android? i already got video from list of images by using javacv.

Comment: @rams Yes, it is possible. Sorry for being so late in answering you back, been in vacation. You may get some good answers in this link https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/javacv